# Setting the size of dataGrids that having been generated on new tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagridview, datagrid

When selecting an excel file. I have new tabs generated for each excel sheet name.  On each tab, I also have a new dataGridView being generated.  How do I set the dimensions of the new dataGridView set up automatically without physically clicking and dragging them in the design view?  This code provide takes my sheet names from the excel file, creates my new tabs with those names, and creates the dataGridViews for each tab... Just need to have the sizes of the dgv's much bigger.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
        {
            string name = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            var tabPage = new TabPage(name);
            DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();

            tabPage.Controls.Add(grid);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(name);
            tabControl2.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the DataGridView to take up all available space, you can initialize the DataGridView's Dock property with DockStyle.Fill:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    string name = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    var tabPage = new TabPage(name);
    DataGridView grid = new DataGridView {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };

    tabPage.Controls.Add(grid);
    comboBox1.Items.Add(name);
    tabControl2.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
}
```

Setting DockStyle.Fill makes sure the DataGridView's edges dock to the edges of its containing control and is sized properly.

Alternatively you can choose to set the position and size yourself:

```
grid.Location = new Point(500, 500);
gird.Size = new Size(500, 500);
```